# foreach not looping correctly for a webservice

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have and array that is being produced from a webservice.

```
Array ( 
    [TPA_Extensions] => Array (
        [TPARoomDetail] => Array ( 
            [GuestCounts] => Array ( 
                [GuestCount] => Array ( 
                        [!AgeQualifyingCode] => 10 
                        [!Count] => 1
                ) 
            ) 
            [!Occupancy] => Single 
            [!OccupancyCode] => SGL 
        ) 
    ) 
    [!IsRoom] => true 
    [!Quantity] => 1 
    [!RoomType] => Palace Gold Club Room 
    [!RoomTypeCode] => PGC 
)
```

My foreach loop is as below

```
foreach ($roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"] as $guestcount) {

echo "guest count1->";print_r($guestcount);
echo "guest count2->";  print_r($roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"]);
}
```

The output i get is 
guest

```
count1->10 guest count2->Array ( [!AgeQualifyingCode] => 10 [!Count] => 1 )
```

guest count1 should have been an array

```
Array ( [!AgeQualifyingCode] => 10 [!Count] => 1 )  but it comes as an int 10 ..
```

why is that so ..?

Comment: `guest count1` is first element of `$roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"]` is `[!AgeQualifyingCode] => 10`

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct, *`$guestcount`* holds the number '10',

where **`$roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"]`**
hold an array.

this is your loop:

```
foreach ($roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"] as $guestcount) {

  echo "guest count1->";print_r($guestcount);
  echo "guest count2->";  print_r($roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"]);
}
```

ths loop will run 2 times, because that's the number of childs in **GuestCount** array.
it will be '10', then '1', exactly reflecting the structure of your array:

```
[!AgeQualifyingCode] => 10 
[!Count] => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing wrong in the code as 1st index holds integer value and 2nd index holds array. However your method of accessing array value are very complicated and doesn't looks good. You an access the array values and keys in more effective manner as follows.

1)Create a method that takes path of the array you want to access

For example According to your code if I want to access **AgeQualifyingCode** key than I have to write  $roomType["TPA_Extensions"]["TPARoomDetail"]["GuestCounts"]["GuestCount"]["AgeQualifyingCode"].

This doesn't looks good, wouldn't it be great if you just have to pass the path of key you want to access the value to.

For example: /TPA_Extensions/TPARoomDetail/GuestCounts/GuestCount/AgeQualifyingCode

You just have to define a function that takes the path of the key, and will return value for that key

```
<?php

    function path($path=null){
        if($path){
            $array = $theNameOfOriginalArray
            $path  = explode('/',$path);

            foreach($path as $sub){
                if(isset($array[$sub])){
                    $array = $array[$sub];
                }
            }

            return $array;
        }
    }

    $value = path('TPA_Extensions/TPARoomDetail/GuestCounts/GuestCount/AgeQualifyingCode');
    //will return 10
?>
```